# How to remove Youtube branding after embedding video in flutter

Tags: flutter, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I want to play a YouTube video in my Flutter app with the ability to hide EVERYTHING (Channel name, Video Title, and YouTube logo).

- I initially attempted using the `youtube_player_flutter` package, but it proved incapable of achieving this.
- Subsequently, I tried the `youtube_player_iframe` package, which claims to be 100% customizable. However, I couldn't find a way to hide everything. If you have any insights, please let me know.

[image]

I've made an attempt to achieve this. With my current approach, I've successfully hidden the YouTube logo and details from the video. However, I'm facing an issue with autoplay functionality not working. Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

*If it's possible to achieve this using the youtube_player_iframe package, please provide guidance on how to implement it.*

```
class YoutubePlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoId;

  const YoutubePlayerWidget({Key? key, required this.videoId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YoutubePlayerWidgetState createState() => _YoutubePlayerWidgetState();
}

class _YoutubePlayerWidgetState extends State<YoutubePlayerWidget> {
  late WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenHeight = screenWidth * (16 / 9);

    String youtubePlayerHtml =
        '''
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>
            body {
              margin: 0;
              overflow: hidden;
            }
            iframe {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <iframe
            width="$screenWidth"
            height="$screenHeight"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${widget.videoId}?controls=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0"
            frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen
            id="youtubeIframe"
          ></iframe>
        </body>
      </html>
    ''';

    return SizedBox(
      height: screenHeight,
      width: screenWidth,
      child: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'about:blank',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
          _controller.loadUrl(
              Uri.dataFromString(youtubePlayerHtml, mimeType: 'text/html')
                  .toString());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot do this because it is indeed a webview. https://pub.dev/packages/pod_player can be used.

Comment: My current attempt seems to work well, except for the autoplay feature. Despite setting 'autoplay=1, I'm encountering issues, and I'm uncertain about the reason behind the non-functional autoplay.